# Error concerning url parameter while testing view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, rspec3

Running the provided spec fails, and I think it might be related to the url parameters, being territories/:id/.

> Error received :

```
1) territories/edit.html.erb shows a form with the data already in it
     Failure/Error: <%= form_for(territory, remote: true) do |territory_form| %>

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"territories", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :locale=>#<Territory id: 2, name: "Territory 4", lent_on: "2015-12-21", returned_on: "2015-12-21", lent_to: 6, created_at: "2015-12-23 10:04:15", updated_at: "2015-12-23 10:04:15">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I'm working with `form_for`. I find it a bit weird that I receive an error about the url parameter in my view, while I'm not having anything directly related to it in the view code.

I've put the controller code as wel, just for clarity.

Can someone guide me how to either fix this or how to properly test this

> edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Territories#edit</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/territories/edit.html.erb</p>

<%= render partial: "territory_form", locals: { territory: @territory } %>
```

> edit.html.erb_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "territories/edit.html.erb", type: :view, territories:true do
  before(:each) do
    @territory = create(:territory)
    render
  end

  it "shows a form with the data already in it" do
    puts "Body: #{rendered}"
    expect(rendered).to have_css("label", :text => "Name")
    expect(rendered).to have_css "input[value*='#{@territory.name}']"
  end
end
```

> routes.rb

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                     Controller#Action
  sessions_new GET    (/:locale)/sessions/new(.:format)               sessions#new {:locale=>/en|nl/}
   sign_up_new GET    (/:locale)/sign_up/new(.:format)                sign_up#new {:locale=>/en|nl/}
         users GET    (/:locale)/users(.:format)                      users#index {:locale=>/en|nl/}
     edit_user GET    (/:locale)/users/:id/edit(.:format)             users#edit {:locale=>/en|nl/}
          user GET    (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)                  users#show {:locale=>/en|nl/}
               PATCH  (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)                  users#update {:locale=>/en|nl/}
               PUT    (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)                  users#update {:locale=>/en|nl/}
               DELETE (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)                  users#destroy {:locale=>/en|nl/}
      register GET    (/:locale)/register(.:format)                   users#new {:locale=>/en|nl/}
               POST   (/:locale)/register(.:format)                   users#create {:locale=>/en|nl/}
         login GET    (/:locale)/login(.:format)                      sessions#new {:locale=>/en|nl/}
               POST   (/:locale)/login(.:format)                      sessions#create {:locale=>/en|nl/}
        logout DELETE (/:locale)/logout(.:format)                     sessions#destroy {:locale=>/en|nl/}
      overview GET    (/:locale)/user/overview(.:format)              dashboard#index {:locale=>/en|nl/}
   territories GET    (/:locale)/admin/territories(.:format)          territories#index {:locale=>/en|nl/}
               POST   (/:locale)/admin/territories(.:format)          territories#create {:locale=>/en|nl/}
 new_territory GET    (/:locale)/admin/territories/new(.:format)      territories#new {:locale=>/en|nl/}
edit_territory GET    (/:locale)/admin/territories/:id/edit(.:format) territories#edit {:locale=>/en|nl/}
     territory GET    (/:locale)/admin/territories/:id(.:format)      territories#show {:locale=>/en|nl/}
               PATCH  (/:locale)/admin/territories/:id(.:format)      territories#update {:locale=>/en|nl/}
               PUT    (/:locale)/admin/territories/:id(.:format)      territories#update {:locale=>/en|nl/}
               DELETE (/:locale)/admin/territories/:id(.:format)      territories#destroy {:locale=>/en|nl/}
               GET    /:locale(.:format)                              sessions#new
          root GET    /                                               sessions#new
```

> territories_controller.rb

```
class TerritoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @territories = Territory.all.order(:name) #Must be changed to use pagination
  end

  def new
    @territory = Territory.new
  end

  def import

  end

  def create
    @territory = Territory.new(create_params)
    if (!@territory.save)
      render action: :create and return
    end

    render action :new
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
    @territory = Territory.find(edit_params)
  end

  def update
    territory_params = update_params
    @territory = Territory.find(territory_params[:id])

    if (!@territory || !@territory.persisted?)
      render index and return
    end

    @territory.update(territory_params[:territory])
  end

  def destroy
  end


  private
  def create_params
    params.require(:territory).permit(:name)
  end

  def edit_params
    params.require(:id)
  end

  def update_params
    id = params.require(:id)
    territory = params.require(:territory).permit(:name)
    {:id => id, :territory => territory}
  end
end
```

> territory_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(territory, remote: true) do |territory_form| %>
  <p>
    <%= territory_form.label :name %>
    <%= territory_form.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <%= territory_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Made it into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/daneov/8087abd1319d2354b677)

Answer (score 0):

```
def edit
  @territory = Territory.find(edit_params)
end
```

Should just be

```
def edit
  @territory = Territory.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: This would just remove the requirement for the parameter id, right? So in what way should it solve it ? I realized I forgot to include the error message, so added it now. [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/daneov/8087abd1319d2354b677) has the gist with the entire stacktrace